# when flipping four coins with heads probabilities

Tags: probability

Let  X  be the number of heads when flipping four coins with heads probabilities 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, and 0.8. Find E(X).

Comment: I have to use the approach od find expected value =1*0.3+2*0.4+3*0.7+4*0.8=6.4

Comment: I don't know where I'm wrong the defination of expected value is p1*x1+p2*x2....pn*xn

Comment: You have to approach this differently. First, ask yourself: What is the probability that there will be exactly one Heads? And after that: What is the probability that there will be exactly two Heads? etc ...

Comment: ok thanks, I can solve it

Comment: you can use linearity of expectation and avoid the long formula. E.g. The first coin is flipped once, you expect 0.3 heads on that flip. Similarly for the other coins. By linearity the expected number of heads in the four flips is is $0.3+0.4+0.7+0.8 =2.2$. ... you don't need to find the full distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You really just use the formula.

As you said, let $X$  be the number of heads in a toin coss. Then $P(X)$ is the probablity for getting $X$ heads. You then use

$$E(X) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^4 X_k P(X_k) = 1 * P(1) + 2 * P(2) + 3 * P(3) + 4 * P(4) $$

You confused $P(k)$ with the probablity of the $k$-th coin, when in reality, it is the probability to a number of heads equal to $k$.

That is for $P(4)$ all coins must show up heads, i.e.

$$P(4) = 0.3 \cdot 0.4 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.8 = 0.0672$$

For $P(3)$ this gets a little more tricky, because you have four different possibilities (each of the coins can show tails instead). So you have to use the **complementary probability**

$$P(3) = 0.3 \cdot 0.4 \cdot 0.7 \cdot \mathbf{0.2} + 0.3 \cdot 0.4 \cdot \mathbf{0.3} \cdot 0.8 + 0.3 \cdot \mathbf{0.6} \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.8+ \mathbf{0.7} \cdot 0.4 \cdot 0.7 \cdot 0.8 = 0.3032 $$

Now do the same for $P(2)$ and $P(1)$. It can be helpful to write down all the possible outcomes first.

For $P(2)$ that would be

> HHTT
>   HTHT
>   HTTH
>   THHT
>   THTH
>   TTHH

Comment: the E(X) is 2.1992

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1$,$X_2$,$X_3$,$X_4$ be the four coins following bernoulli distribution with probability of head being $0.3,0.4,0.7,0.8$ respectively.

By linearity of expectation, $E(X) = E(X_1)+E(X_2)+E(X_3)+E(X_4)$

with $E(X_i) = p_i$

Thus $E(X) = 0.3+0.4+0.7+0.8 = 2.2$

If you do the way the other responder asks you to do will also endup in 2.2.

[image]

Goodluck